# Boton que no funciona

Tags: html5

Hola a todos y gracias por anticipado.
Tengo un simple formulario con `Nombre`, `email`, `Mensaje` y un boton de Enviar.
el código del botón es:

```
  <div class="form-field col x-100 align-center">
         <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </div>
```

El problema es que no veo como incluir el action por más que he probado.
¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: No has introducido el código, edita y ponlo bien así te podemos ayudar.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el resto de código del formulario?

Comment: Hola user, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: No se como meter el action para que este formulario envíe : 
https://www.codeseek.co/ainarela/contact-form-XXZymN

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo como seria un formulario para hacer un submit.

```
<form action="pagina.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

El `action` es a donde va a ir la pagina cuando le des al botón, el boton del formulario tiene que tener el atributo `type="submit"` asi realiza el postback.

**Ten cuidado con las comillas en los atributos.**

**Edit**: Veo que has añadido código a la pregunta que no estaba antes.

**Tienes un botón que tiene un tipo `submit`, pero no veo que este dentro de un `form`. Si el botón no esta dentro de un form no hace submit, en el form es donde se especifica a donde va a ir el formulario.**

**Edit 2:**

El `action` va dentro de la etiqueta principal form. [Aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp) tienes la documentación de como funciona.

```
   <form class="contact-form row" action="pagina.php">
      <div class="form-field col x-50">
         <input id="name" class="input-text js-input" type="text" required>
         <label class="label" for="name">Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-field col x-50">
         <input id="email" class="input-text js-input" type="email" required>
         <label class="label" for="email">E-mail</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-field col x-100">
         <input id="message" class="input-text js-input" type="text" required>
         <label class="label" for="message">Message</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-field col x-100 align-center">
         <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
      </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: Hola Emiliano , gracias por tus comentarios ,  estoy utilizando este código: codeseek.co/ainarela/contact-form-XXZymN
Y en el contacto.html entiendo que estoy en un form no? Debajo de la etiqueta h1  esta el fom class ... la verdad es que estoy liado...
El caso es que no me funciona cuando meto el action dentro de la sentencia input class...

Comment: Edito la respuesta para añadir el codigo, te lo he añadido en el Edit 2.

Answer (score 0):

El action no va en el botón, sino en la cabecera del formulario.

```
   <form action=tupagina.php>
         ... (resto de código)
   <button name="Este es el botón"></button>
   </form>
```

Comment: en realidad para que el formulario se envíe el botón debe ser de tipo submit, o bien un input de tipo submit.

Comment: Pues no acaba de chutar...
Estoy  intentando que funcione este ejemplo:
https://www.codeseek.co/ainarela/contact-form-XXZymN

Comment: Se puede poner un <form dentro de otro <form ?
Lo pregunto porque en el código aparece un <form class y esto es lo que me lía... no se si ese vale para añadirle el action o no se puede , las pruebas que he hecho hasta ahora no me han funcionado. Gracias por anticipado. Saludos !

Comment: Sí, sí se puede, pero tienen que tener actions distintos, o sea, dirigir hacia diferentes páginas.

Comment: Puedes pegar el código completo y así hago una prueba de lo que quieres hacer?